# Align top a few rows wouldn't work in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, alignment, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

why Microsoft Access 2010 can't align unbound fields correctly?
**Or what's wrong?**

The A is a position group with "Unbound".
And B is a group with Data B, C with Data C, D with Data D and E with Data E.

So the problem is, that if i align all to top, it works fine for data fields.
The unbound textbox is in/overlays the label field.

I would align all fields below each other.

```
A
Unbound
B
Data B
C
[...]
```

And as you can see its really wrong at the moment. :(

**Before:**

[image: Before i align top]

**Now i align:**

[image: I do it]

**After:**

[image: After i did it]

**Thanks in Advance for any information!**

Comment: Can you share information about what your intent is? It seems trivial but you could align it the way you want by hand as you did in your screenshot.

Comment: The "Unbound" textbox slides in the label. Thats the problem! I would have all fields below each other. With all fields it works except the unbound field.

Comment: Check the control padding values - perhaps the combo box is different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have found a bug in Access 2010.  Is this causing some sort of issue for you? (i.e. can you arrange the controls manually?)